# Installed new SSD now when my mac dies to freezes on restart

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, battery, hibernate

I've installed a new SSD not an OEM, but it's a compatible fit to my early macbook pro 2015 with retina 13". When my battery dies it doesnt hibernate my mac, so when I restart it, it freezes and then I have to hold the power button to force it to turn off. When it does boot, I get the following report. I've no idea how to read this so any help would be appreciated.

```
Anonymous UUID:       27082FFD-D0D3-F92A-D827-BEC6D1920688

Sat Jun  4 11:51:29 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff800e59b0d4): launchd exited (signal 10, exit status 0 )

uuid info:
 0x7fff609ea000 uuid = <a468d85e-d8d6-3461-8c99-49d3b9acfc63>
 0x105597000    uuid = <48362449-4519-317e-9a8b-7524036de5ea>

Thread 1 crashed

RAX: 0xffffffffffffffff, RBX: 0x00007fff860081b8, RCX: 0x00007fff899fd3aa, RDX: 0xffffffffffffffff
RSP: 0x0000700000116e28, RBP: 0x0000700000116e40, RSI: 0x0000000000000000, RDI: 0x00007fff860081b8
R8:  0x0000000000000000, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0x00007fff899fd3aa, R11: 0x0000000000000207
R12: 0x00007fff719fd180, R13: 0x00007fff719fd1c0, R14: 0x00007fff719fd1b8, R15: 0x0000000000000000
RFL: 0x0000000000010206, RIP: 0x00007fff8600766a, CS:  0x000000000000002b, SS:  0x0000000000000023

Thread 0: 0xffffff8020b9c920
    0x00000001055c114b
    0x00007fff943f052a
    0x0000000000000000
    0x00007fff85fec665
    0x00007fff85fec64e
    0x00007fff85fe90b5
    0x00007fff85fe8dcd
    0x0000000000000000

Thread 1: 0xffffff8020b9cdb0
    0x00007fff85ff77b5
    0x0000000000000000

Thread 2: 0xffffff8020b9d240
    0x00000001055ae529
    0x00007fff85fe340b
    0x00007fff85fe803b
    0x00007fff85fee707
    0x00007fff85fe340b
    0x00007fff85fe729b
    0x00007fff85fe6b00
    0x00007fff82fa54de
    0x00007fff82fa3341
    0x0000000000000000

Thread 3: 0xffffff8021ac2db0
    0x00007fff83324605
    0x00007fff833245a8
    0x00007fff82fa73dc
    0x00007fff82fa6f63
    0x00007fff82fa5582
    0x00007fff82fa3341
    0x0000000000000000

Thread 4: 0xffffff8020ccbb60
    0x00007fff82fa3341
    0x0000000000000000

Mac OS version: 15F34
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 15.5.0: Tue Apr 19 18:36:36 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3248.50.21~8/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 7E7B0822-D2DE-3B39-A7A5-77B40A668BC6
System model name: MacBookPro12,1 (Mac-E43C1C25D4880AD6)
Model: MacBookPro12,1, BootROM MBP121.0167.B16, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.7 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.28f7
Graphics: Intel Iris Graphics 6100, Intel Iris Graphics 6100, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x483943434E4E4E424C54414C41522D4E5544
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x483943434E4E4E424C54414C41522D4E5544
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x133), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.95.175.1a6)
Bluetooth: Version 4.4.5f3 17904, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: OWC Aura SSD, 479.95 GB
Serial ATA Device: MARVELL VIRTUAL
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Card Reader
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 27.1
```

Comment: The 2015 (Early/Mid) MBP uses a **proprietary** SSD; OWC is the only company I know of that makes "compatible" SSDs.  That said, did you do a restore or a clean installation?  I always prefer to do a clean install.

Comment: That's who I used OWC and I've confirmed with their technical support that I'm using a compatible SSD. I did a clean install. I've aso reset the PRAM and SMC, but not change.

Comment: My mac functions fine in general usage, but as soon as the battery dies it doesn't restart properly.

Comment: Does OS X warn you that the battery is  going to die?

Comment: No I haven't had any warning like that, and the problem has only occurred since the upgrade. Does the log above indicate anything do you know?

Comment: I've found my sleep settings too:

Jonathans-MBP:vm jonathanlockley$ pmset -g
Active Profiles:
Battery Power  1*
AC Power  2
Currently in use:
 standbydelay         10800
 standby              0
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 gpuswitch            2
 powernap             0
 disksleep            10
 sleep                1 (sleep prevented by iTunes, coreaudiod)
 autopoweroffdelay    14400
 hibernatemode        3
 autopoweroff         1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         2
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1

Comment: That could be a coincidence that it happened after the upgrade.  "exit status 0 " means a normal (no error) exit.  I don't know what "signal 10" is in this context, but I can tell you that the "signal" sent by another process telling launchd to exit was what caused it to exit.  Put back the old SSD and see if the problem persists.